# Hide specific intent filters

Tags: share-menu, intents

I have several apps on my device that has multiple intent filters, which clutters the menu when I want to open a file(e.g. PDF). I would like to hide some of these intent filters, as I do not need them.

This is a picture of the intent chooser:

[image: Intent filters]

I know that iOS has an option to hide these targets under the "More" menu, can this be done on Android? I am using One UI 2 (Samsung) and MIUI 10 (Xiaomi).

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My Samsung tablet isn't rooted, so I can use this app. Is there another way to do this on my rooted phone?

Comment: [See related questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=Better+open+with)

Comment: You can self answer the question in future by posting it in answer box and not by editing the question//In this case, it's already marked as duplicate

Comment: Hello. I have rolled back the question to the version where it didn't contain the answer. We appreciate that you want to provide an answer, but we also want to preserve our Q&A format (that is, questions should remain as questions, and so do the answers). :-) As beeshyams stated above, self-answering is the  correct way to go.

Comment: This question is closed, how do I provide an answer? Thanks.